# Finding commas inside a char array

Tags: c

I have 2 problems with this function:

```
char * getHeader( char localString[], int seperatorNum)
{
    int maxL=50;
    const char seperator=':';
    char newdata[maxL];
    int counter=0;
    for(int k=0;k<maxL;k++)
    {
        if ( localString[k]==  seperator   )
        {
            counter++;
            if(counter==seperatorNum)
            { Serial.println(newdata);    return newdata;     } 
        }
         newdata[k]=localString[k];
    }
}
```

1. When I print the `newdata` I get garbage, but `localString[k]` is showing good results.
2. How would I return the array-is my way good?

Edit: i am getting bb after each and every result .  so :

```
aaa:sss (send)
aaabb    (get)
kkk:ooo  (send)
kkkbb   (get)
ppp:ttt
pppbb
```

Comment: It's not hard to spell **I** correctly, you know. Sure people gets it, but correct spelling shows respect to people reading your question.

Comment: `:` is a colon. A comma is `,`.

Comment: where is newdata being modified that you wouldn't see garabage?

Comment: code was for comma and changed, i dont think its matters so much here..

Comment: ("I" is always written in upper case in English.)

Comment: new data is always garbage , but localString[k] always get the right chars and stops at the right time, but seems that the newdata is not copying the localString[k] ..

Comment: `newdata` is printed *before* it's assigned. It's junk data because you haven't given it a value before printing it.

Comment: no. there is a for loop , and i never see its data even in the third iteration.

Comment: for aaa:bbb if i print newdata[k] i get garbage but localString[k] i get a a a

Comment: how about just switching those 2 lines set than print

Comment: so stupid to down vote , someone is coming here, asking something, English is not his mother language like you , and all you do is finding English mistakes, great person you are

Comment: switching them will not give you anything. if you think about it for a minute, there is a for loop and if i send it aaa:bbb there are 3 iterations , and i dont see any of them.

Comment: @Curnelious: don't assume that people that are _helping you write a better question_ are also downvoting you.

Comment: Moving the assignment past the print will print the right data.. right now you print the old char before assigning the new one, on each loop pass.  However, you're also not null terminating the new string (or returning its length somehow), and you're returning a pointer to a local array.

Comment: that is not true! check my edit, even if you put the print where i put it now, you would get garbage- that means letters that never was in the original string

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, I speak Chinese. I would correct the spellings in the quesiton if it's coming from a new user, but you are obviously not. It's also obvious that you *know* how to spell them correctly but you didn't, in all these comments.

Comment: The comma/colon mix-up doesn't matter too much in terms of the problem and solution, but it is kind of confusing and should be fixed in the question.

Comment: Please edit this question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's okay that your English isn't perfect, but it would help **a lot** if you provided a full example. We can't replicate your results because we don't have the *complete* code. Provide a complete and minimal example, with inputs, outputs, and expected results, and that will help this question a lot.

Comment: i had. copy this function send it data aaa:bbbb and see what you get . The fact that you dont have the answer doesn't mean you have to look for other things in my question that are "not good" .

Comment: No, you haven't provided a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. [You're missing code](http://ideone.com/0vVhwQ). It's not *complete* or *verifiable* if I can't copy 'n' paste it to run it. It also doesn't look *minimal*. Until you do, I'm voting to close, as this is just too confusing. You've had three answers posted, and all you can say is "not working". If you put in some extra effort to help us help you, this will go much better.

Comment: At first, you passed `Serial.println` a `char`, before you assigned it a value.  Now you've moved it, and pass it a `char *` for the whole string... they can't both be right, and some of the comments assumed that (with the first version) you were printing one char at a time.

Comment: see my new edit please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearing the array , which would have some values in it, would solve this, and this is because when you print it, and there are some other values in it, you get them printed too

```
  for( int i = 0; i < maxL;  ++i )
   newdata[i] = (char)0;
```

solve it completely .

EDIT:
And to anyone who needs, this is the complete function that works :

```
char * getHeader( char localString[], int seperatorNum)
{


   int maxL=50;
   const char seperator=':';
   char newdata[maxL];
   int counter=0;
   int divider=0;
   //clear array when it has garbage it added
   for( int i = 0; i < maxL;  ++i )
      newdata[i] = (char)0;

   for(int k=0;k<maxL;k++)
   {


        if ( localString[k]==  seperator   )
       {

           counter++;
           divider=k+1;
           if(counter==seperatorNum)
           {   return newdata;     } 
       }
         if(  (seperatorNum-1) ==counter)
             newdata[k-divider]=localString[k];

   }


 }
```

Comment: You don't need to clear the *whole* array, you just need to make sure to clear the byte after the last character.  Also, you shouldn't return `newdata` since it's a non-static array local to the function -- it's not valid after your function returns.  You could make `newdata` static, but then each call uses the same array.. or return a dynamically allocated array instead.. or allow the user to pass an array to the function, and fill that.  Also, you need add a return to the end in case a separator is never found.

Answer (score 1):

```
newdata[k]=localstring[k];
```

If should come just after

```
for(int k=0;k<maxL;k++)
 {
 //here
```

And if that is not solving it then please provide related complete 
code.

Comment: no,again this is not the right answer. check my edit please.

Comment: if i am sending this function aaaa:bbbb i should get 4 iterations, so first is not good , others are good.

Comment: @Curnelious check update and please also tell what  values are u passing as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * getHeader( char localString[], int seperatorNum)
{ 
    int maxL=50;
    const char seperator=':';
    char newdata[maxL];
    memset(newdata, '\0', maxL);///////
    int counter=0;
    int i = 0; ///////
    for(int k=0;k<maxL;k++)
    {
        if ( localString[k] ==  seperator   )
        {
            counter++;
            if(counter == seperatorNum)
            { 
                Serial.println(newdata);    
                return newdata;     
            } 
        }else{
           newdata[i] = localString[k];//outside the else this was alway executed.  I assume you didn't want the seperator in this
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. thanks. check it out with aaa:bbbb you get garbage .

Comment: its not working and actually i dont think its the case. because if you send it aaa:bbbb (for the forth time)  you WILL have a few iterations ,

Comment: made modification with memset